# Hide Columns Based on Combobox (Form) In Excel

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have everything setup with different options for forecasts. I have done this in the past at a different job and I can't figure out where I am going wrong.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

  If ComboBox1.Value = "2 Weeks" Then
      Columns("J:L").Select
      Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
      Columns("M:R").Select
      Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  End If

  If ComboBox1.Value = "6 Weeks" Then
      Columns("M:O").Select
      Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
      Columns("J:L").Select
      Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
      Columns("P:R").Select
      Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  End If

  If ComboBox1.Value = "12 Weeks" Then
      Columns("P:R").Select
      Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
      Columns("J:O").Select
      Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: for future, post the actual code, not a picture. Lots of people will copy and paste code into excel themselves to test, here they have to retype.

Comment: You need to say what it's doing wrong.

Comment: I am slightly confused. Are you using a Form Control or an ActiveX Control?

Comment: Sorry I thought I was helping people, still not used to the protocol. And it isn't doing anything at all. In the title I included it was a form control.

Comment: But the code looks like it is for an ActiveX Control. :)

Comment: what'd you do to fix it? this will eat at me as it looks to me also it should work

Comment: @user1759942, he just put in the text, replacing the picture.

Comment: hahaha i thought he figured it out XXPPPP

Comment: Got meeting I will check back after. Thanks for you work thus far everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your code should work just fine. I rewrote it to be more concise and it worked perfectly (with an Active-X control).

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Select Case ComboBox1.Value
  Case "2 Weeks"
    Columns("J:L").Hidden = False
    Columns("M:R").Hidden = True
  Case "6 Weeks"
    Columns("J:L").Hidden = True
    Columns("M:O").Hidden = False
    Columns("P:R").Hidden = True
  Case "12 Weeks"
    Columns("J:O").Hidden = True
    Columns("P:R").Hidden = False
End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: That looks nice. For some reason my sheet doesn't do anything. I have it saved to the prper sheet. Could it be that I am treating this like and ActiveX and not form. ^^ Thanks to Siddharth.

Comment: @phentrus, it could be.  Are you sure you have design mode turned off?

Comment: The code just works. Since the code is hiding the entire columns, it may seem like nothing happened ... but it hides the required columns.

Comment: @SiddharthRout, yes, I was going to add more, but you put up a good answer, so I'll just upvote that.

Comment: Oops just saw your comment. I already added an answer... Sorry.

Comment: @SiddharthRout, that's fine, I like yours.

Comment: I changed it to an ActiveX and everytime I try to input the ListFillRange it empties when I click somewhere else. If that will stick, i am sure the marco will work. Excel is not treating me well today.

Comment: @phentrus, you need to put a range in the ListFillRange, then in the Range you noted put the values you want, so put `A1:A3`, then in A1: 2 weeks, A2: 6 Weeks, A3: 12 Weeks.

Comment: Eveything falls into place. I thought I could put the header above the list and it would autofill the range. That was 2007, no? You guys rock. :)

Comment: @phentrus, you could use a named range, which is nice if you might ever have the need to add to it.

Comment: @phentrus: `I changed it to an ActiveX..` You can't change your question like this :) Especially after people have answered your actual query. Not that I have any problems in you accepting Lance's answer but this defeats the purpose of a Q&A site. I would recommend amending your question (as a one of case) so that any future visitors do not get confused as to how the activeX control code can work for a form control code.

Answer (score 3):

> In the title I included it was a form control. – phentrus 8 mins ago

The reason why I was confused and asked you in the comments above whether you are using a form control or an ActiveX control is because your quesiton title says "Form" but the code is for ActiveX.

For Form Control, paste this code in a module.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DropDown1_Change()
    Dim DDown As Shape

    Set DDown = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)

    Select Case DDown.ControlFormat.List(DDown.ControlFormat.ListIndex)
        Case "2 Weeks"
            Columns("J:L").Hidden = False
            Columns("M:R").Hidden = True
        Case "6 Weeks"
            Columns("J:L").Hidden = True
            Columns("M:O").Hidden = False
            Columns("P:R").Hidden = True
        Case "12 Weeks"
            Columns("J:O").Hidden = True
            Columns("P:R").Hidden = False
    End Select
End Sub
```

Next right click your Form Combobox and assign the above macro to it :)

Comment: Did you mean 'Hidden' instead of 'HiDDownen'?

Comment: @LanceRoberts: LOL I certainly did

Comment: this must be completely on me. When I try to assign macros, the list is empty now.

Comment: @phentrus: Did you paste the code in a module (not in the sheet code area)